# Get link to sheet in image

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

how can i go to a specific sheet when i click on the image? I need to go to the "FERMENTADOR 2_002 / 2021" sheet when the user clicks on the "fermenter" image.

the problem is that the name of the sheet may change according to some criteria ... so the sheet to be activated needs to be with the value of cell A4 + the value of cell B16

```
function hyperlink(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var nomeferm = sheet.getRange("A4").getValue();
  var numlote = sheet.getRange("B16").getValue();
  var pagina = nomeferm+"_"+numlote;

  var tt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(pagina);

}
```

[image: image reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Code based on your comment:**

```
function getToSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('HOME');
  const name = sh.getRange('A4').getValue()+"_"+sh.getRange('B16').getValue();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  if(sheet){
      ss.setActiveSheet(sheet, true);
  }
}
```

### Solution:

I guess the most straightforward way is to attach the following very simple script to your image:

```
function getToSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('FERMENTADOR 2_002/2021'), true);
}
```

- The script will activate sheet `FERMENTADOR 2_002/2021` therefore it will redirect you there.
- You just need to **assign** this script to your image and then you can click on the image itself (see attached gif).

### Illustration:

[image]